# Windows service terminates unexpectedly in windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-services

I have written a windows service that catches a UDP message, creates a process as user, sends the message to the process via named pipes, and repeats. Service works great in XP but terminates unexpectedly in windows 7 after one iteration. Event Viewer shows that after I pass my message to the service there is an application error followed by the unexpected termination of my service. Application error says faulting module is ntdll.dll. Debugging my service shows where the code stops.

Here is my work loop.

```
do
{
     DebugLog("Waiting For UDP message");
    if(recvfrom(socketId, buffer, buffSize, 0, &clientAddrCast, &size) >= 0)
    {
         DebugLog("Create Named Pipe");
        hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(lpszPipename,       // pipe name
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,     // read/write access
                PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |     // message pipe
                PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE,  // message read mode
                1,                      // maximum Instaces
                buffSize,               // output buffer size
                buffSize,               // input buffer size
                5000,                   // client time-out
                &pSecAttrib);           // security attributes

        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ErrorLog("CreateNamedPipe");


         DebugLog("Create User Process");
        if(!CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDupe, "C:\\Services\\UDPClient_UserApp.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, dwCreationFlags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))  
        {

            // if client app fails use SendMessage as failsafe
            //WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionID, pTitle, sizeof(pTitle), 
                //buffer, sizeof(buffer), MB_OK, 30, &resp, false);
                ErrorLog("CreateProcess");
        }
        else
        {
             DebugLog("Writing to User Process");
            // Open pipe to client
            if(cSuccess = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) == 0)
                ErrorLog("ConnectNamedPipe");
            else
            {
                Sleep(2000);

                cbToWrite = (lstrlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);

                if(!WriteFile( 
                  hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
                  buffer,                 // message 
                  cbToWrite,              // message length 
                  &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
                  NULL))                  // not overlapped 
                  ErrorLog("WriteFile");
            }
        }

    }

    DebugLog("Cleanup");
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
    ErrorLog("test");     

}while(gServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING);
```

My debug logs in XP show that after `DebugLog("Cleanup")` it loops back to `DebugLog("Waiting For UDP message")`. In windows 7 it stops after `DebugLog("Cleanup")`. I am looking into problems my code may create. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joseph G.

Comment: Sorry about that. It fails somewhere after `DebugLog("Cleanup")` is called. I have already edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be tighter security in Win7 is getting you.

There's missing code here, what's in `pSecAttrib` for example?  Beef up your error handling so (for example) you don't execute the rest of the loop body if pipe creation fails, and you know exactly which API failed and why.

`CreateProcessAsUser` - what user are you running the service as? Does that user have the right permissions - they may be different on Win7 versus WinXP.

Log `GetLastError()` value after **all** Win32 failures.  Make your own life easier, this could be in Production in a remote site one day and how will you troubleshoot it then?

What's that `Sleep(2000);` for?  Suspicious.  If the pipe is open why not just send the data and avoid this delay.  Is the Named Pipe server code this slow to post a read request on the pipe?

Comment: `pSecAttrib` gets the active users security attributes.
`CreateProcessAsUser` is set to run as the active user.

Comment: `GetLastErrot` is called in all the `ErrorLog` functions.
The `Sleep(2000)` is there because the process created by the service takes to long to open its end. It may not need a whole 2 seconds. That number was placed there arbitrarily.

Comment: Good to hear you are logging the errors. I am curious about the call to DestroyEnvironmentBlock. This is inside the loop but I don't see init inside the loop. That could be a bug though I'd think that would fail on the second pass not the first (unless you don't init `pEnv` at all?). Can't you get a proper callstack by running this in the debugger until you hit the exception? You should be able to do better than "after the cleanup log" in narrowing this down. Also, check **all** Win32 API calls for error. If one fails and you miss that fact, behaviour further on is likely to be unexpected.

Comment: After playing with the code for a while i noticed that `pEnv` was being initialized outside the scope of the loop. Upon further research i discovered that the process I was creating did not even need its own environment. I completely removed all code related to `pEnv` and my service now works fine.

Comment: That's great, glad to hear you are underway again.